# How can I transfer array type from swagger.json into List[int] in python rather than list[int]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

There is a parameter's type is **array** in swagger json. When I convert it into python apilib, the type transfer into **list[int]**.

I use it to define method like this:

```py
def get_receipts_by_ids_with_http_info(self, authorization:str, request_body:list[int]):
    pass
```

Python does'nt support parameter define in this way. If I verify it like bellow, it works:

```py
def get_receipts_by_ids_with_http_info(self, authorization:str, request_body:List[int]):
    pass
```

How can I transfer **array** type into **List[int]** in python?

Comment: json to list is done using import json.  Please provide an extract of the json and I will demonstrate